# Flask module cannot be found in pyvenv although it is installed

Tags: flask

I used the following commands to create the virtual environment and run my code:

mkdir ~/.virtualenvs
pyvenv ~/.virtualenvs/bitirme
source ~/.virtualenvs/bitirme/bin/activate
pip3 install flask
pip3 install httpie
python3 server.py

Although flask is installed correctly I still get the error that flask module cannot be found. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You did something wrong. Hard to say what with the information you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in the normal way (i guess, that you on *NIX):

1. Install "virtualenv" module via pip
2. Go to the directory, where you wanna create virtual environment
3. Type in terminal "virtualenv %name% %python_path%"
4. Now to activate, do "./%name%/bin/activate"
5. Install "pip install flask httpie"
6. Run "python server.py"

**NOTE:**

If you created virtual environment with your "python 3"
installation, you should not add "3" to python, or pip

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I was told to use python 3.5 with my code so basically forced to use pyvenv. The first time I installed it, it was working perfectly when I checked it and although I did nothing else, next time I tried it stopped working.